# scapy stuck when using sendp and works for sr1

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy

In my ifconfig i am having **eth1** device with this config

```
eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.64.1.0  netmask 255.0.0.0  broadcast 192.255.255.255
        inet6 fe80::826d:97ff:fe52:9994  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 80:6d:97:52:99:94  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4838411  bytes 1344955238 (1.3 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5073767  bytes 6561153691 (6.5 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

If I am using

```
sr1(IP(dst="192.64.22.7")/ICMP())
```

I am getting reply and i can see request and reply in wireshark.

```
>>> a=sr1(IP(dst="192.64.22.7")/ICMP())
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets.
.........*
Received 10 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
```

If i am using sendp the scapy will remain stuck without sending

```
sendp(Ether()/IP(dst="192.64.22.7",ttl=(1,4)), iface="eth1")
```

same for

```
srp1(Ether()/IP(dst="192.64.22.7")/ICMP(), verbose=True)
```

the result looks like this in python terminal, but it wont comes to next prompt in terminal

```
>>> srp1(Ether()/IP(dst="192.64.22.7")/ICMP(), verbose=True)
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets.
```

Why the Layer 2 message is not getting send, what am i missing here?